# Get DATE from DOY does not work for DOY 1

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to get the Date for a DOY / YEAR combination.

```
    public String getDateFromDoy(int doy, int year) {
    // 1st Try
    Year y = Year.of(year) ;
    LocalDate ld = y.atDay(doy) ;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.YYYY  EEE");
    String formattedString = ld.format(formatter);
    
    // 2nd Try
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();//Calendar.getInstance();
    if(year > 0) calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, doy);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY  HH:mm:ss EEE");
    System.out.println("Day of year " + doy + " = " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    
    return formattedString;//sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

It works as expected for all days, except DOY 1, I got 2022 instead of 2023

```
getDateFromDoy(1, 2023);
getDateFromDoy(2, 2023);
getDateFromDoy(3, 2023);


Day of year 1 = 01.01.2022  07:39:01 So.
Day of year 2 = 02.01.2023  07:39:01 Mo.
Day of year 3 = 03.01.2023  07:39:01 Di.
```

I tried 2 differend solutions, the 1st of January is always wrong.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Your first try works perfectly.  Perhaps you should print out `formattedString` instead of the string produced by SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @VGR the problem was (as mentioned above by the moderator) that I used YYYY (calendar week based year) instead of yyyy.